# Embed Frame in Panel

Tags: java-8, awt

I have a third party `Frame` component that I want as a panel in another window.

Is there a way to embed it in some way so that I don't have two windows?

I tried adding it directly to the panel, but that threw an exception `adding a window to a container`.

Is there a way of doing this? Something like just making the graphics object that the `Frame` is rendering to the something that points at a space on the panel or similar?

If it matters, I don't need the embedded window to accept any user input.

Comment: Unlikely. There are too many assumptions made in the AWT’s processing. E.g. some components simply won’t draw anything as long as they aren’t descendants of a *visible window*. You could simply remove the child components of the second window and add them to your first, but if the Frame has been subclassed to customize things, that won’t work. Also, 3rd party code connected to these components could cause havoc when the components are reparented.

Comment: @Holger Do you think there is a way to copy the graphical output of one window into another? (even if the third party widget window was still visible, just copying it) and having it show in both places.

Comment: No reliable way… too many corner cases…

Answer (score 0):

There are too many assumptions made in the AWT’s processing. E.g. some components simply won’t draw anything as long as they aren’t descendants of a visible window. You could simply remove the child components of the second window and add them to your first, but if the Frame has been subclassed to customize things, that won’t work.